# Complexity of preimage resistance

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance

Why is the complexity of pre-image resistance $2$ raised to the power of $n$?
I have been looking in everything lecture about pre-image resistance, but I still didn't know the answer.

Comment: What is "2 square by n"? $\;$

Comment: I would say $2^n$.

Answer (score 4):

When the output of the hash function is $n$ bits, then there are $2^n$ possible outputs.

For a preimage attack you are given a hash $h$ and you need to find a message $m$ where $h = H(m)$.

Since there are $2^n$ possible outputs, the probability of guessing an input that that maps to the given output is $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$. So on average you need to try $2^n$ preimages. That is where the $2^n$ complexity comes from.